# How can I work with second python file from main file?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two python files,  first is main.py file that load basic.ui and second.py file is a pyqt5 window that created from qt designer with one button that when it press it It close the window. I want all the commands to handle ONLY from first main.py file not second.py file. How can I do that?

Can I load multiple ui files from main.py file with `uic method?`

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys

from second import Ui_SecondWindow



from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('basic.ui', self)
        ...
        ...
       
        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(lambda: self._secondWindow())
     
       
        self.show()

    def _secondWindow(self):
        self.secondWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_Second()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.secondWindow)
        self.secondWindow.close()



app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

second.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Second):
        ...
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Second)
        ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Second = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_secondWindow
    ui.setupUi(Second)
    Second.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like to solve my problem. I prefer answers with examples. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the main part and put this into the setup fuction. Then you can have only one entry point in the programm.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a minimally reproducible example.

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but try this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
# ??? from second import Ui_SecondWindow


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):  #, Ui_SecondWindow):      # ??? Ui_SecondWindow
    def __init__(self):                                      
        super().__init__()  

#        self.setupUi(self)                                       # ??? Ui_SecondWindow

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Close SecondWindow', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)  


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        
# ?        uic.loadUi('basic.ui', self)                                  # ???  basic.ui
        
        #...
       
#-        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(lambda: self._secondWindow())
#+        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(self._secondWindow)          # ???  basic.ui

        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QPushButton('open secondWindow', self)
        self.actionAbout.clicked.connect(self._secondWindow) 
        
        self.secondWindow = SecondWindow()                                # +++

    def _secondWindow(self):
#        self.secondWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
#        self.ui = Ui_Second()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self.secondWindow)
#        self.secondWindow.close()
        
        self.secondWindow.show()                                          # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()                         
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @S Nick Can you tell me how the app works without this line? `uic.loadUi('basic.ui', self)` . Your solution It didn't work.